# When re-render the listview , why the value in former <TextInput/> was kept?

Tags: react-native

Here's the code:

```
var FAKE_DATA = [
{
    type: 0,
},
{
    type: 1,
},]

var FAKE_DATA_2 = [
{
    type: 0,
},
{
    type: 1,
},
{
    type: 2,
},]

export default class testpage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    let listData = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (p1, p2) => {
            p1 !== p2
        },
    });

    this.state = {
        data: listData.cloneWithRows(FAKE_DATA)
    }
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ListView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}

                dataSource={this.state.data}
                renderRow={this.renderRow} />


            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        data: this.state.data.cloneWithRows(FAKE_DATA_2)
                    })
                } }
                style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
                />

        </View>
    );
}


renderRow(data) {
    return (
        <TextInput style={{ height: 40, }} />
    )
}}
```

And when I typed something in textinput and click the button ,the listview was updated but the value in textinput remains in new textinput.Is it bug?Or just the way it works?How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to manually clear your textInput on button click. You can try this:

```
  clearText: function() {
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  },
```

Simply invoke this function on button click.

Comment: Thanks ! It seems that RN cache the object for reuse?So what if i want to release some object?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the TextInput value prop to the data in `renderRow`, it should pick it up.

Also, you have an issue in your ListView.DataSource initializer:

```
rowHasChanged: (p1, p2) => {
  p1 !== p2
},
```

The function is correct, however, you're not returning inside the brackets so it will never say the row has changed.

It should be

```
rowHasChanged: (p1, p2) => p1 !== p2,
```

or

```
rowHasChanged: (p1, p2) => {
  return p1 !== p2
},
```